# Doctrine CLI outputs contents of doctrine.php

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

i followed an online tutorial on integrating doctrine 2 and ZF2. i am able to insert data to database but whenever i run doctrine CLI it outputs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd "../doctrine/orm/bin"
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/doctrine.php"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

which is the content to doctrine.php that i replaced with codes frome tutorial.

Comment: What command are you actually running?  That is not a PHP file at all but a shell script.

Comment: yes it is shell script. i used composer to install doctrine on zend studio 9 in windows 8. that content was in doctrine.php which i needed to replace with the code from http://www.oelerich.org/integrate-doctrine-2-with-zend-framework-1-11-3/

Comment: I wonder how you can run Posix commands on a Windows system. Better choose a tutorial that is for your operating system otherwise you're just asking for trouble. So don't wonder that it does not work, it was not intended to work on Windows 8.

Comment: got the same issue. Did you have a solution yet? I'm on windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the path to doctrine binaries (containing "doctrine", "doctrine.php", "doctrine.bat"...

Go to the root of your project, and type:

```
php path_to_doctrine_bin/doctrine.php [options]
```

That should do it.

Comment: @sanders which problem? Using my method you never get to touch the shell script, so there shouldn't any output like shown on the original post. If you get the same problem, please give more detailed steps about what you actually do, and we'll help you

Answer (score 5):

I found this on another question here and it works on Windows.
There are also a bin folder in vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/ you can use this one like this in your console commands:

php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you need to run the .bat files instead. eg.

```
vendor\bin\doctrine.bat orm:schema-tool:create
```

Comment: This isn't the case and will result in the same error OP was already having.

Answer (score 1):

Face the same problem , it turns out using forward slash instead of backward slash was the real culprit

So move inside the project directory and do

```
vendor\bin\doctrine.bat orm:schema-tool:create
```

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is to use the *original* shell/bash script in the `vendor` dir (running on win7)

```
$ vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```